# CentOS 6.5 server time zone won't persist?

Tags: centos, timezone

I'm setting my timezone like so:

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London /etc/localtime
```

It works fine, I check with `date` and all is good.

But then a few days later I'll realise it's reset itself to CEST, so 9am becomes 10am, etc.

The server is located in Paris, in the CEST time zone.  But I should be able to use any zone I want, surely?  I (and most of my users) am based in the UK, so I want to operate on that timezone.

I just did a yum update and noticed it wanted to update tzdata.  That had the effect of changing from BST to CEST, but I don't think it's the only thing that triggers the change, as I'm sure it's gone wrong on days where I've done no such update.  I could be wrong though.

What's the trick to set a timezone **permanently**?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple upon further googling.  Editing `/etc/sysconfig/clock` to say London instead of Paris did the trick.  `yum reinstall tzdata` with clock set to Paris triggered the problem, but `yum reinstall tzdata` with clock set to London has the desired effect.